# Using an alert in an actionsheet in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm using a actionsheet in react native  and need it to generate an alert once a button is clicked. The buttons are in the array provided under the `BUTTONS` variable. The code is shown below:

```
const BUTTONS = [
      { text: "SMS", icon: "chatboxes", iconColor: "#2c8ef4" },
      { text: "Email", icon: "analytics", iconColor: "#f42ced" },
      { text: "Push Notification", icon: "aperture", iconColor: "#ea943b" },
      { text: "Delete", icon: "trash", iconColor: "#fa213b" },
      { text: "Cancel", icon: "close", iconColor: "#25de5b" }
    ];
    const DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX = 3;
    const CANCEL_INDEX = 4;
return(
...
ActionSheet.show(
              {
                options: BUTTONS,
                cancelButtonIndex: CANCEL_INDEX,
                destructiveButtonIndex: DESTRUCTIVE_INDEX,
                title: "How do you want to receive your notification"
              },
              buttonIndex => {
                setSheet({ clicked: BUTTONS[buttonIndex] });
              }
            )
```